# How to approximate a surface plot to a Matlab contour

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following plot

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{dfsa3c.dat}
0.12    0.5 0.
0.12    1.5 0.
0.12    2.5 0.
0.12    3.5 0.
0.12    4.5 0.
0.12    5.5 0.
0.12    6.5 0.
0.12    7.5 0.
0.12    8.5 0.
0.12    9.5 0.
0.12    10.5    0.
0.12    11.5    0.
0.12    12.5    0.
0.12    13.5    0.
0.12    14.5    0.
0.12    15.5    0.
0.12    16.5    0.
0.12    17.5    0.
0.12    18.5    0.

0.16    0.5 0.
0.16    1.5 0.
0.16    2.5 0.
0.16    3.5 0.
0.16    4.5 0.
0.16    5.5 0.
0.16    6.5 0.
0.16    7.5 0.
0.16    8.5 0.
0.16    9.5 0.
0.16    10.5    0.
0.16    11.5    0.
0.16    12.5    0.
0.16    13.5    0.
0.16    14.5    0.
0.16    15.5    0.
0.16    16.5    0.
0.16    17.5    0.
0.16    18.5    0.

0.2 0.5 0.
0.2 1.5 0.
0.2 2.5 0.
0.2 3.5 0.
0.2 4.5 0.
0.2 5.5 0.
0.2 6.5 0.
0.2 7.5 0.
0.2 8.5 0.
0.2 9.5 0.
0.2 10.5    0.
0.2 11.5    0.
0.2 12.5    0.
0.2 13.5    0.
0.2 14.5    0.
0.2 15.5    0.
0.2 16.5    0.
0.2 17.5    0.
0.2 18.5    0.

0.24    0.5 0.
0.24    1.5 0.
0.24    2.5 0.
0.24    3.5 0.
0.24    4.5 0.
0.24    5.5 0.
0.24    6.5 0.
0.24    7.5 0.
0.24    8.5 0.
0.24    9.5 0.012333333333333333
0.24    10.5    0.101
0.24    11.5    0.2747278202455409
0.24    12.5    0.46103719793646486
0.24    13.5    0.5046684223126646
0.24    14.5    0.483661499790532
0.24    15.5    0.5092097445038621
0.24    16.5    0.5
0.24    17.5    0.5021666666666667
0.24    18.5    0.506

0.28    0.5 0.
0.28    1.5 0.
0.28    2.5 0.
0.28    3.5 0.
0.28    4.5 0.
0.28    5.5 0.
0.28    6.5 0.0006666666666666666
0.28    7.5 0.035
0.28    8.5 0.4125
0.28    9.5 0.9543333333333334
0.28    10.5    1.
0.28    11.5    1.
0.28    12.5    1.
0.28    13.5    1.
0.28    14.5    1.
0.28    15.5    1.
0.28    16.5    1.
0.28    17.5    1.
0.28    18.5    1.

0.32    0.5 0.
0.32    1.5 0.
0.32    2.5 0.
0.32    3.5 0.
0.32    4.5 0.
0.32    5.5 0.00525
0.32    6.5 0.4053333333333333
0.32    7.5 0.907
0.32    8.5 0.996
0.32    9.5 1.
0.32    10.5    1.
0.32    11.5    1.
0.32    12.5    1.
0.32    13.5    1.
0.32    14.5    1.
0.32    15.5    1.
0.32    16.5    1.
0.32    17.5    1.
0.32    18.5    1.

0.36    0.5 0.
0.36    1.5 0.
0.36    2.5 0.
0.36    3.5 0.
0.36    4.5 0.
0.36    5.5 0.1665
0.36    6.5 0.9516666666666667
0.36    7.5 1.
0.36    8.5 1.
0.36    9.5 1.
0.36    10.5    1.
0.36    11.5    1.
0.36    12.5    1.
0.36    13.5    1.
0.36    14.5    1.
0.36    15.5    1.
0.36    16.5    1.
0.36    17.5    1.
0.36    18.5    1.

0.4 0.5 0.
0.4 1.5 0.
0.4 2.5 0.
0.4 3.5 0.0007524454477050414
0.4 4.5 0.07252856433184302
0.4 5.5 0.71425
0.4 6.5 0.9996666666666667
0.4 7.5 1.
0.4 8.5 1.
0.4 9.5 1.
0.4 10.5    1.
0.4 11.5    1.
0.4 12.5    1.
0.4 13.5    1.
0.4 14.5    1.
0.4 15.5    1.
0.4 16.5    1.
0.4 17.5    1.
0.4 18.5    1.

0.44    0.5 0.
0.44    1.5 0.
0.44    2.5 0.
0.44    3.5 0.013
0.44    4.5 0.489
0.44    5.5 0.988
0.44    6.5 1.
0.44    7.5 1.
0.44    8.5 1.
0.44    9.5 1.
0.44    10.5    1.
0.44    11.5    1.
0.44    12.5    1.
0.44    13.5    1.
0.44    14.5    1.
0.44    15.5    1.
0.44    16.5    1.
0.44    17.5    1.
0.44    18.5    1.

0.48    0.5 0.
0.48    1.5 0.
0.48    2.5 0.
0.48    3.5 0.1725
0.48    4.5 0.9245
0.48    5.5 0.99925
0.48    6.5 1.
0.48    7.5 1.
0.48    8.5 1.
0.48    9.5 1.
0.48    10.5    1.
0.48    11.5    1.
0.48    12.5    1.
0.48    13.5    1.
0.48    14.5    1.
0.48    15.5    1.
0.48    16.5    1.
0.48    17.5    1.
0.48    18.5    1.

0.52    0.5 0.
0.52    1.5 0.
0.52    2.5 0.001
0.52    3.5 0.522
0.52    4.5 1.
0.52    5.5 1.
0.52    6.5 1.
0.52    7.5 1.
0.52    8.5 1.
0.52    9.5 1.
0.52    10.5    1.
0.52    11.5    1.
0.52    12.5    1.
0.52    13.5    1.
0.52    14.5    1.
0.52    15.5    1.
0.52    16.5    1.
0.52    17.5    1.
0.52    18.5    1.

0.56    0.5 0.
0.56    1.5 0.
0.56    2.5 0.0045
0.56    3.5 0.758137205808713
0.56    4.5 0.9990029910269193
0.56    5.5 1.
0.56    6.5 1.
0.56    7.5 1.
0.56    8.5 1.
0.56    9.5 1.
0.56    10.5    1.
0.56    11.5    1.
0.56    12.5    1.
0.56    13.5    1.
0.56    14.5    1.
0.56    15.5    1.
0.56    16.5    1.
0.56    17.5    1.
0.56    18.5    1.

0.6 0.5 0.
0.6 1.5 0.
0.6 2.5 0.055
0.6 3.5 0.927122464312547
0.6 4.5 1.
0.6 5.5 1.
0.6 6.5 1.
0.6 7.5 1.
0.6 8.5 1.
0.6 9.5 1.
0.6 10.5    1.
0.6 11.5    1.
0.6 12.5    1.
0.6 13.5    1.
0.6 14.5    1.
0.6 15.5    1.
0.6 16.5    1.
0.6 17.5    1.
0.6 18.5    1.

0.64    0.5 0.
0.64    1.5 0.
0.64    2.5 0.2115
0.64    3.5 0.9932364729458918
0.64    4.5 1.
0.64    5.5 1.
0.64    6.5 1.
0.64    7.5 1.
0.64    8.5 1.
0.64    9.5 1.
0.64    10.5    1.
0.64    11.5    1.
0.64    12.5    1.
0.64    13.5    1.
0.64    14.5    1.
0.64    15.5    1.
0.64    16.5    1.
0.64    17.5    1.
0.64    18.5    1.

0.68    0.5 0.
0.68    1.5 0.
0.68    2.5 0.384
0.68    3.5 0.999498997995992
0.68    4.5 1.
0.68    5.5 1.
0.68    6.5 1.
0.68    7.5 1.
0.68    8.5 1.
0.68    9.5 1.
0.68    10.5    1.
0.68    11.5    1.
0.68    12.5    1.
0.68    13.5    1.
0.68    14.5    1.
0.68    15.5    1.
0.68    16.5    1.
0.68    17.5    1.
0.68    18.5    1.

0.72    0.5 0.
0.72    1.5 0.
0.72    2.5 0.5045
0.72    3.5 1.
0.72    4.5 1.
0.72    5.5 1.
0.72    6.5 1.
0.72    7.5 1.
0.72    8.5 1.
0.72    9.5 1.
0.72    10.5    1.
0.72    11.5    1.
0.72    12.5    1.
0.72    13.5    1.
0.72    14.5    1.
0.72    15.5    1.
0.72    16.5    1.
0.72    17.5    1.
0.72    18.5    1.

0.76    0.5 0.
0.76    1.5 0.0005
0.76    2.5 0.6215
0.76    3.5 1.
0.76    4.5 1.
0.76    5.5 1.
0.76    6.5 1.
0.76    7.5 1.
0.76    8.5 1.
0.76    9.5 1.
0.76    10.5    1.
0.76    11.5    1.
0.76    12.5    1.
0.76    13.5    1.
0.76    14.5    1.
0.76    15.5    1.
0.76    16.5    1.
0.76    17.5    1.
0.76    18.5    1.

0.8 0.5 0.
0.8 1.5 0.00175
0.8 2.5 0.7495
0.8 3.5 1.
0.8 4.5 1.
0.8 5.5 1.
0.8 6.5 1.
0.8 7.5 1.
0.8 8.5 1.
0.8 9.5 1.
0.8 10.5    1.
0.8 11.5    1.
0.8 12.5    1.
0.8 13.5    1.
0.8 14.5    1.
0.8 15.5    1.
0.8 16.5    1.
0.8 17.5    1.
0.8 18.5    1.

0.84    0.5 0.
0.84    1.5 0.004
0.84    2.5 0.873
0.84    3.5 1.
0.84    4.5 1.
0.84    5.5 1.
0.84    6.5 1.
0.84    7.5 1.
0.84    8.5 1.
0.84    9.5 1.
0.84    10.5    1.
0.84    11.5    1.
0.84    12.5    1.
0.84    13.5    1.
0.84    14.5    1.
0.84    15.5    1.
0.84    16.5    1.
0.84    17.5    1.
0.84    18.5    1.

0.88    0.5 0.
0.88    1.5 0.01825
0.88    2.5 0.94325
0.88    3.5 1.
0.88    4.5 1.
0.88    5.5 1.
0.88    6.5 1.
0.88    7.5 1.
0.88    8.5 1.
0.88    9.5 1.
0.88    10.5    1.
0.88    11.5    1.
0.88    12.5    1.
0.88    13.5    1.
0.88    14.5    1.
0.88    15.5    1.
0.88    16.5    1.
0.88    17.5    1.
0.88    18.5    1.

0.92    0.5 0.
0.92    1.5 0.07
0.92    2.5 0.988
0.92    3.5 1.
0.92    4.5 1.
0.92    5.5 1.
0.92    6.5 1.
0.92    7.5 1.
0.92    8.5 1.
0.92    9.5 1.
0.92    10.5    1.
0.92    11.5    1.
0.92    12.5    1.
0.92    13.5    1.
0.92    14.5    1.
0.92    15.5    1.
0.92    16.5    1.
0.92    17.5    1.
0.92    18.5    1.
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
zlabel={$f(x,y) = x\cdot y$},
title=DFSA,
small,view={0}{90},colorbar,
]

    \addplot3 [surf,
        patch type=bilinear,
        ]
        table {dfsa3c.dat};
\end{axis}
    %%%%%
    \begin{axis}[xshift=8cm,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
         title=DFSA,
        small,view={0}{90},colorbar,
    ]
           \addplot3 [surf,
            shader=flat,
            patch type=bilinear,patch refines,
            ]
            table {dfsa3c.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

is the solution of the question["Heatmap from XYZ data points in a file"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482975/heatmap-from-xyz-data-points-in-a-file)
.

I would like to get a solution similar to this one

[image]

I have tested `contour gnuplot = filled`

```
      \begin{axis}[xshift=8cm,
          xlabel=$x$,
          ylabel=$y$,
         title=DFSA,
          small,view={0}{90},colorbar,
           ]
           \addplot3 [surf,
           shader=interp, contour gnuplot = filled]
            table {dfsa3c.dat};
        \end{axis}
```

but the result is not complete, and I would prefer the plot without the isoline labels if possible.

Regards

[image]

Comment: Switching off the labels in the contour plot is easy: just add `labels=false`, i.e. `\addplot3 [surf,
           shader=interp, contour gnuplot ={filled,labels=false}]
            table {dfsa3c.dat};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER**: This is written by a marmot with basically zero knowledge on gnuplots, so ....

Switching off the labels is easy. The more delicate question is how one may possibly get something of the sort of your MatLab plot. (Did I mention that I never in my life used MatLab?)

Two observations that may help here:

1. A lot can be learned from [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122980/121799).
2. You can play with point meta to stretch the region with many contours. (Alternatively you could use `levels={<some appropriate list>}`.)

Note that the result can not be seen with all viewers, see p. 162 of the pgfplots manual (after reading it I finally understood [KJO's comment here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482975/heatmap-from-xyz-data-points-in-a-file#comment1220958_482987), sorry @KJO!!!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{dfsa3c.dat}
0.12    0.5 0.
0.12    1.5 0.
0.12    2.5 0.
0.12    3.5 0.
0.12    4.5 0.
0.12    5.5 0.
0.12    6.5 0.
0.12    7.5 0.
0.12    8.5 0.
0.12    9.5 0.
0.12    10.5    0.
0.12    11.5    0.
0.12    12.5    0.
0.12    13.5    0.
0.12    14.5    0.
0.12    15.5    0.
0.12    16.5    0.
0.12    17.5    0.
0.12    18.5    0.

0.16    0.5 0.
0.16    1.5 0.
0.16    2.5 0.
0.16    3.5 0.
0.16    4.5 0.
0.16    5.5 0.
0.16    6.5 0.
0.16    7.5 0.
0.16    8.5 0.
0.16    9.5 0.
0.16    10.5    0.
0.16    11.5    0.
0.16    12.5    0.
0.16    13.5    0.
0.16    14.5    0.
0.16    15.5    0.
0.16    16.5    0.
0.16    17.5    0.
0.16    18.5    0.

0.2 0.5 0.
0.2 1.5 0.
0.2 2.5 0.
0.2 3.5 0.
0.2 4.5 0.
0.2 5.5 0.
0.2 6.5 0.
0.2 7.5 0.
0.2 8.5 0.
0.2 9.5 0.
0.2 10.5    0.
0.2 11.5    0.
0.2 12.5    0.
0.2 13.5    0.
0.2 14.5    0.
0.2 15.5    0.
0.2 16.5    0.
0.2 17.5    0.
0.2 18.5    0.

0.24    0.5 0.
0.24    1.5 0.
0.24    2.5 0.
0.24    3.5 0.
0.24    4.5 0.
0.24    5.5 0.
0.24    6.5 0.
0.24    7.5 0.
0.24    8.5 0.
0.24    9.5 0.012333333333333333
0.24    10.5    0.101
0.24    11.5    0.2747278202455409
0.24    12.5    0.46103719793646486
0.24    13.5    0.5046684223126646
0.24    14.5    0.483661499790532
0.24    15.5    0.5092097445038621
0.24    16.5    0.5
0.24    17.5    0.5021666666666667
0.24    18.5    0.506

0.28    0.5 0.
0.28    1.5 0.
0.28    2.5 0.
0.28    3.5 0.
0.28    4.5 0.
0.28    5.5 0.
0.28    6.5 0.0006666666666666666
0.28    7.5 0.035
0.28    8.5 0.4125
0.28    9.5 0.9543333333333334
0.28    10.5    1.
0.28    11.5    1.
0.28    12.5    1.
0.28    13.5    1.
0.28    14.5    1.
0.28    15.5    1.
0.28    16.5    1.
0.28    17.5    1.
0.28    18.5    1.

0.32    0.5 0.
0.32    1.5 0.
0.32    2.5 0.
0.32    3.5 0.
0.32    4.5 0.
0.32    5.5 0.00525
0.32    6.5 0.4053333333333333
0.32    7.5 0.907
0.32    8.5 0.996
0.32    9.5 1.
0.32    10.5    1.
0.32    11.5    1.
0.32    12.5    1.
0.32    13.5    1.
0.32    14.5    1.
0.32    15.5    1.
0.32    16.5    1.
0.32    17.5    1.
0.32    18.5    1.

0.36    0.5 0.
0.36    1.5 0.
0.36    2.5 0.
0.36    3.5 0.
0.36    4.5 0.
0.36    5.5 0.1665
0.36    6.5 0.9516666666666667
0.36    7.5 1.
0.36    8.5 1.
0.36    9.5 1.
0.36    10.5    1.
0.36    11.5    1.
0.36    12.5    1.
0.36    13.5    1.
0.36    14.5    1.
0.36    15.5    1.
0.36    16.5    1.
0.36    17.5    1.
0.36    18.5    1.

0.4 0.5 0.
0.4 1.5 0.
0.4 2.5 0.
0.4 3.5 0.0007524454477050414
0.4 4.5 0.07252856433184302
0.4 5.5 0.71425
0.4 6.5 0.9996666666666667
0.4 7.5 1.
0.4 8.5 1.
0.4 9.5 1.
0.4 10.5    1.
0.4 11.5    1.
0.4 12.5    1.
0.4 13.5    1.
0.4 14.5    1.
0.4 15.5    1.
0.4 16.5    1.
0.4 17.5    1.
0.4 18.5    1.

0.44    0.5 0.
0.44    1.5 0.
0.44    2.5 0.
0.44    3.5 0.013
0.44    4.5 0.489
0.44    5.5 0.988
0.44    6.5 1.
0.44    7.5 1.
0.44    8.5 1.
0.44    9.5 1.
0.44    10.5    1.
0.44    11.5    1.
0.44    12.5    1.
0.44    13.5    1.
0.44    14.5    1.
0.44    15.5    1.
0.44    16.5    1.
0.44    17.5    1.
0.44    18.5    1.

0.48    0.5 0.
0.48    1.5 0.
0.48    2.5 0.
0.48    3.5 0.1725
0.48    4.5 0.9245
0.48    5.5 0.99925
0.48    6.5 1.
0.48    7.5 1.
0.48    8.5 1.
0.48    9.5 1.
0.48    10.5    1.
0.48    11.5    1.
0.48    12.5    1.
0.48    13.5    1.
0.48    14.5    1.
0.48    15.5    1.
0.48    16.5    1.
0.48    17.5    1.
0.48    18.5    1.

0.52    0.5 0.
0.52    1.5 0.
0.52    2.5 0.001
0.52    3.5 0.522
0.52    4.5 1.
0.52    5.5 1.
0.52    6.5 1.
0.52    7.5 1.
0.52    8.5 1.
0.52    9.5 1.
0.52    10.5    1.
0.52    11.5    1.
0.52    12.5    1.
0.52    13.5    1.
0.52    14.5    1.
0.52    15.5    1.
0.52    16.5    1.
0.52    17.5    1.
0.52    18.5    1.

0.56    0.5 0.
0.56    1.5 0.
0.56    2.5 0.0045
0.56    3.5 0.758137205808713
0.56    4.5 0.9990029910269193
0.56    5.5 1.
0.56    6.5 1.
0.56    7.5 1.
0.56    8.5 1.
0.56    9.5 1.
0.56    10.5    1.
0.56    11.5    1.
0.56    12.5    1.
0.56    13.5    1.
0.56    14.5    1.
0.56    15.5    1.
0.56    16.5    1.
0.56    17.5    1.
0.56    18.5    1.

0.6 0.5 0.
0.6 1.5 0.
0.6 2.5 0.055
0.6 3.5 0.927122464312547
0.6 4.5 1.
0.6 5.5 1.
0.6 6.5 1.
0.6 7.5 1.
0.6 8.5 1.
0.6 9.5 1.
0.6 10.5    1.
0.6 11.5    1.
0.6 12.5    1.
0.6 13.5    1.
0.6 14.5    1.
0.6 15.5    1.
0.6 16.5    1.
0.6 17.5    1.
0.6 18.5    1.

0.64    0.5 0.
0.64    1.5 0.
0.64    2.5 0.2115
0.64    3.5 0.9932364729458918
0.64    4.5 1.
0.64    5.5 1.
0.64    6.5 1.
0.64    7.5 1.
0.64    8.5 1.
0.64    9.5 1.
0.64    10.5    1.
0.64    11.5    1.
0.64    12.5    1.
0.64    13.5    1.
0.64    14.5    1.
0.64    15.5    1.
0.64    16.5    1.
0.64    17.5    1.
0.64    18.5    1.

0.68    0.5 0.
0.68    1.5 0.
0.68    2.5 0.384
0.68    3.5 0.999498997995992
0.68    4.5 1.
0.68    5.5 1.
0.68    6.5 1.
0.68    7.5 1.
0.68    8.5 1.
0.68    9.5 1.
0.68    10.5    1.
0.68    11.5    1.
0.68    12.5    1.
0.68    13.5    1.
0.68    14.5    1.
0.68    15.5    1.
0.68    16.5    1.
0.68    17.5    1.
0.68    18.5    1.

0.72    0.5 0.
0.72    1.5 0.
0.72    2.5 0.5045
0.72    3.5 1.
0.72    4.5 1.
0.72    5.5 1.
0.72    6.5 1.
0.72    7.5 1.
0.72    8.5 1.
0.72    9.5 1.
0.72    10.5    1.
0.72    11.5    1.
0.72    12.5    1.
0.72    13.5    1.
0.72    14.5    1.
0.72    15.5    1.
0.72    16.5    1.
0.72    17.5    1.
0.72    18.5    1.

0.76    0.5 0.
0.76    1.5 0.0005
0.76    2.5 0.6215
0.76    3.5 1.
0.76    4.5 1.
0.76    5.5 1.
0.76    6.5 1.
0.76    7.5 1.
0.76    8.5 1.
0.76    9.5 1.
0.76    10.5    1.
0.76    11.5    1.
0.76    12.5    1.
0.76    13.5    1.
0.76    14.5    1.
0.76    15.5    1.
0.76    16.5    1.
0.76    17.5    1.
0.76    18.5    1.

0.8 0.5 0.
0.8 1.5 0.00175
0.8 2.5 0.7495
0.8 3.5 1.
0.8 4.5 1.
0.8 5.5 1.
0.8 6.5 1.
0.8 7.5 1.
0.8 8.5 1.
0.8 9.5 1.
0.8 10.5    1.
0.8 11.5    1.
0.8 12.5    1.
0.8 13.5    1.
0.8 14.5    1.
0.8 15.5    1.
0.8 16.5    1.
0.8 17.5    1.
0.8 18.5    1.

0.84    0.5 0.
0.84    1.5 0.004
0.84    2.5 0.873
0.84    3.5 1.
0.84    4.5 1.
0.84    5.5 1.
0.84    6.5 1.
0.84    7.5 1.
0.84    8.5 1.
0.84    9.5 1.
0.84    10.5    1.
0.84    11.5    1.
0.84    12.5    1.
0.84    13.5    1.
0.84    14.5    1.
0.84    15.5    1.
0.84    16.5    1.
0.84    17.5    1.
0.84    18.5    1.

0.88    0.5 0.
0.88    1.5 0.01825
0.88    2.5 0.94325
0.88    3.5 1.
0.88    4.5 1.
0.88    5.5 1.
0.88    6.5 1.
0.88    7.5 1.
0.88    8.5 1.
0.88    9.5 1.
0.88    10.5    1.
0.88    11.5    1.
0.88    12.5    1.
0.88    13.5    1.
0.88    14.5    1.
0.88    15.5    1.
0.88    16.5    1.
0.88    17.5    1.
0.88    18.5    1.

0.92    0.5 0.
0.92    1.5 0.07
0.92    2.5 0.988
0.92    3.5 1.
0.92    4.5 1.
0.92    5.5 1.
0.92    6.5 1.
0.92    7.5 1.
0.92    8.5 1.
0.92    9.5 1.
0.92    10.5    1.
0.92    11.5    1.
0.92    12.5    1.
0.92    13.5    1.
0.92    14.5    1.
0.92    15.5    1.
0.92    16.5    1.
0.92    17.5    1.
0.92    18.5    1.
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[
xlabel=$x$,
ylabel=$y$,
zlabel={$f(x,y) = x\cdot y$},
title=DFSA,
small,view={0}{90},colorbar,
]

           \addplot3 [ patch type=bilinear,
           point meta={tan(3*(z-1/2)*180/pi)},
           contour filled={labels=false}]
            table {dfsa3c.dat};
\end{axis}
    %%%%%
     \begin{axis}[xshift=8cm,
          xlabel=$x$,
          ylabel=$y$,
         title=DFSA,
          small,view={0}{90},colorbar,
           ]
           \addplot3 [surf,
           shader=interp, contour gnuplot ={filled,labels=false}]
            table {dfsa3c.dat};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that this is a screenshot of the result viewed with `acroread`, with `preview` the left plot is empty. (Ah, if you want to go with something along these lines and are bugged by the fact that the scale now longer does not go from 0 to 1, this is something that can be fixed easily.)