# Creating a heatmap from CSV data

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, csv

[This questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482975/heatmap-from-xyz-data-points-in-a-file) solves the same problem I have, but in the example the data comes from `filecontents` and the solution involves changing the data, in my case the data comes from a CSV which I cannot change, is there a way to achieve the same result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I just added another [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583660/95441) to the above mentioned question. This should also solve your problem/question, right?

Comment: Thank you kind stranger! That worked perfectly

Comment: Great, then I will close this question as duplicate. To show that it helped you, you could [upvote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) it (by clicking on the arrows next to the score).